# An open covering of the Topologist's sine curve.

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

How does an open covering of of the topologist's sine curve look like?

I am asking since I want to show that it has a topological dimension 1.

Comment: What is the "topologist's sine curve"? Do you mean the subspace of the graph of the sine function in 2-dimensional real space? Also there are several types of topological dimension: small inductive dimension, large inductive dimension, covering dimension, and for all I know there may be others.

Comment: @user254665 I am refering to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve ; and the topological dimension I am refering to is the one covered in Munkres on page 305: "A space $X$ is called finite dimensional if there is some integer $m$ s.t for every open covering $\mathcal{A}$  of $X$ there's an open covering $\mathcal B$ of $X$ that refines $\mathcal{A}$ and has order at most $m+1$. The topological dimension is defined to the smallest value for which this statement holds;"

Comment: @user254665 or anyone else, can you help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints.An open subset $T$ of  $S=\{(0,0)\}\cup \{(x,\sin 1/x) :0<x<1\}$ is $S\cap T^*$ where $T^*$ is an open subset of the real plane $R^2$. If $(0,0)\in T$ then  $T^*$ covers an open square $$V_r=\{(x,y)\in R^2 : |x|<r \wedge |y|<r\}$$ for some $r>0$. In particular when $T^*=V_r$ we have  $$T=S\cap V_r= \{(0,0)\}\cup \{(x,\sin 1/x) : 0<x<r \wedge |\sin 1/y|<r \}.$$Also, when $0<a<b<1$ and $$S[a,b]= \{(x,\sin 1/x):x\in [a,b]\}$$ and $t>0$, we can cover $S[a,b]$ with a $finite$ family $F$ of open balls of $R^2$,each of radius $t$, each centered at a point of $S[a,b]$.  If $t$ is small enough ( which depends on $a$ and $b$) then $$S\cap (\cup F)=\{(x,\sin 1/x):a-e_1<x<\min (1,1+e_2)\}$$ where $e_1>0<e_2$ and $\max (e_1,e_2)$ can be as small as we like.